# PHP Mysql Array Between

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array of dates.. example:

`$dates = array('2018-06-01', '2018-06-02', '2018-06-03');`

How to find it's exists in between dates without foreach?

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE $dates BETWEEN from AND to;
```

Comment: You're using dates as strings. Did you consider using date-objects? Have a look in the php-manual for it.

Comment: and if it were not date values.. example: $values = array('1', '2', '3'); to search SELECT * FROM table WHERE $values BETWEEN from AND to;

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question converting the datetime field do unix timestamp in query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(from) IN ($dates) OR UNIX_TIMESTAMP(to) IN ($dates)
```

Note: array of dates are converted to unix format and implode ",".

Comment: Unix-timestamp covers data till 2038, afterwards it's just to short.